# Nesting pipelines in apache beam

Tags: tensorflow, apache-beam, tensorflow-transform

I am looking do to the following with apache beam.
Specifically pre-processing for a tensorflow neural network.

- for each file from a folder.

  - for each line from a file

    - process line to 1d list of floats

I need each return to be a 2d list of floats for each file.

I think I can accomplish this by creating nested pipelines.
I could create and run a pipeline inside of a ParDo of another pipeline.

This seems inefficient, but my problem seems like a pretty standard use case.

- Is there a tool to do this better in apache beam?
- Is there a way to restructure my problem to make it work in apache beam better?
- Are nested pipelines not as bad as I think they are?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Beam is a great tool for pre-processing data for machine learning with Tensorflow. More information about this general use case and `tf.Transform` is available in this [post](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/02/preprocessing-for-machine-learning-with.html).

Nothing described seems to indicate the need for "nested pipelines". Processing each line of each file in a directory is a simple `TextIO.Read` transformation. It is unclear what your requirements from now on are, but, in general, separating the line into floats and joining with other lines are straightforward ParDo and grouping operations.

As a general guidance, I'd avoid nested pipelines, and try to break down the problem to fit into a single pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the grouping functions.